# Doctrine2 find by value in field array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, find

i wonder if there is a way to search for a document field looking like :

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $tags;
```

which in database looks like php array interpretation :

```
a:3:{i:0;s:6:"tagOne";i:1;s:6:"tagTwo";i:2;s:8:"tagThree";}
```

now i try to search the entity by a tag tryed

```
public function findByTag($tag) {
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('u')
        ->from("myBundle:Entity", 'u')
        ->where('u.tags LIKE :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', $tag );
    $result=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $result;
}
```

which always returns `array[0]`
just dont get it

i am able to change the way how they are saved
for any help, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you save the data serialized in the table, or it's serialized after getting output in your example?

Comment: The data is saved serialized

Comment: I think if you apply one of the below answers and then apply your unserializer to the output you will get what you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define a `literal` tag for `%` before and/or after the value you want to search; in this case you won't even need to have single quotation before and after your phrase:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u')
    ->from("myBundle:Entity", 'u')
    ->where($qb->expr()->like('u.tags', $qb->expr()->literal("%$tag%")))
$result=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
return $result;
```

You can follow a list of all [Doctrine expr class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

Comment: For a more concise match (and taking @jovan-perovic's idea about excluding partial matches into account), one could use `$serializedTag = serialize($tag); /*…*/ literal("%$serializedTag%")`

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this few months ago - you're missing the `%` wildcards. You could do the following:

```
$qb->select('u')
    ->from("myBundle:Entity", 'u')
    ->where('u.tags LIKE :tag')
    ->setParameter('tag', '%"' . $tag . '"%' );
```

The critical part, obviously, is placing `%` wildcards, **but** you would also need to put `"` (double quotes) for preventing the selection of partial matches (if necessary). Leave those out to include partials as well but since you're searching for the tags I don't think that's the case.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answers and one thought expressed in a comment of mine, I decided to use this general static function to do the job:

```php
/**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param string                 $entity
     * @param string                 $arrayField
     * @param string                 $string
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function findByStringInArrayField(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        string $entity,
        string $arrayField,
        string $string
    ): array {
        $serializedString = serialize($string);
        $columnName       = $entityManager->getClassMetadata($entity)->getColumnName($arrayField);
        $qb               = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

        return $qb->select('u')
                  ->from($entity, 'u')
                  ->where(
                      $qb->expr()
                         ->like(
                             "u.$columnName",
                             $qb->expr()->literal("%$serializedString%")
                         )
                  )
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
    }
```

…and would call it from within a `ServiceEntityRepository` like that:

```php
$entities = self::findByStringInArrayField($this->getEntityManager(), MyEntity::class, 'tags', $tag);
```